# flutter pull_to_refresh makes webview unscrollable

Tags: android, flutter

I have a webview inside ZoomDrawer and SmartRefresher and the webview becomes unscrollable as soon as i implemented SmartRefresher. and funny thing is, it works well in iOS but in Android, is not. I'm wondering if there's anybody having the same issue because i couldn't find simillar case online. 
Below there's structure of my app
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried to reproduce the issue but in the question you have said that it is scrolling in the **IOS** while doesn't in **Android**, the thing that controls the scrolling behavior in Flutter is called `scrollPhysics`, which is by default set to:

`BouncingScrollPhysics`, which provides the bouncing overscroll behavior found on **iOS**.
`ClampingScrollPhysics`, which provides the clamping overscroll behavior found on **Android**.

So try to set the `scrollPhysics` property to `BouncingScrollPhysics` to match the **IOS** behavior which might be a solution for the issue.

For a reference in `scrollPhysics`, check the **See also** section on top of the following [page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html).

Comment: I've gave SmartRefresher an property `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()` then it scrolls. but into an blank not the rest of WebView, any ideas?

Comment: Can you publish a minimal example of the issue on GitHub or any equivalent in order to do further debugging?